# SSIS How do I suppress CR/LF in a flat file destination?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, newline, flat-file

I have an error report that consists of a simple query output to a .csv flat file. The last column generated is nvarchar(1000) and holds notes that often include  CR/LF within the text. When you open the .csv in Excel these CR/LF trigger new columns, so half of the notes from the 6th column end up on the next row in the first column.

When I run the query in SSMS I have a query option to "Retain CR/LF on copy or save." If I copy the query results directly to Excel with this option on I recreate the problem. If I remove this option the result does not have the breaks. This is what I want from my SSIS package.

By default SSIS retains CR/FL on save, and I can't find any option to turn that off. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you setting the Text Qualifier in your flat file destination connection manager? You could also use a Row Delimiter that isn't {CR}{LF}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if handling this in the query itself would be an option for you, but if it would you could try removing the CRLF using `REPLACE`:

```
SELECT
    col_first,
    col_second,
    ...
    REPLACE(REPLACE(col_last, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '') AS col_last
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I considered that, but decided it would also remove the valid CR/LF at the end of each line. As it turns out, you're absolutely right. It worked!

Comment: You might want to change the replacement text to something that adds a space. I'd probably use something like this: `REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(col_last, CHAR(13), '~'), CHAR(10), '~'), '~~', ' ')`

Comment: @digital.aaron Yes, that is a good suggestion, but as the OP has accepted this, I will let my answer stand as is for right now.